# Does scrypt use a hash algorithm?

Tags: security, cryptography, scrypt

Does the scrypt program use a hashing algorithm behind the scenes?

What's the output size of scrypt (I mean the underlying algorithm, is that 4096 bits)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output size is whatever you ask PBKDF2 for; IIRC this is limited to something on the order of 4 GB.

Comment: Yes it seems the output size is whatever I want (up to 4096-bits), shouldn't we then just always choose the highest figures? Where do you draw the line -- how much maximum time etc. you want to choose?

Comment: @rFactor: Do you mean for the output size, or the other parameters (memory used/parallelism/etc)?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it does.  In fact, it uses two.  If you look at the [scrypt paper](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt.pdf), you'll see that it uses

1. [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-256) in the [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) construction for initial key expansion and for the final output generation, and
2. the [Salsa 20/8 core](http://cr.yp.to/salsa20.html) by D. J. Bernstein as part of the actual memory-hard mixing function SMix.

(The Salsa 20/8 core is not actually a cryptographic hash function in the same sense as, say, SHA-256, but merely a part of one, but I've included it for completeness.)